# Find distinct dates from times

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have an array that looks like the following:

`[Wed Jan 04 21:56:08 UTC 2012, Thu Jan 12 21:58:36 UTC 2012, Thu Jan 12 22:13:24 UTC 2012, Thu Jan 12 22:13:34 UTC 2012]`

What's the best way in Ruby to count the distinct days only in that array? Jan 12 2012 shows up three times, but it should only be counted once as I only care about Month/Day/Year and not the actual time that the value showed up in the array.

So the total count for this array after filtering should be a count of 2 for 2 distinct Month/Day/Year values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are those strings or DateTime objects? Assuming the latter, and supposing the array is called `datetime_arr`...

```ruby
date_arr = datetime_arr.map &:to_date
# => [Wed, 04 Jan 2012, Thu, 12 Jan 2012, Thu, 12 Jan 2012, Thu, 12 Jan 2012]

date_arr.uniq!
# => [Wed, 04 Jan 2012, Thu, 12 Jan 2012]

date_arr.length
# => 2
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have an accepted answer, I wanted to note that if you are iterating a list of items and you want to do something once for each particular grouping (such as output a header) you should use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for convenience:

```
require 'date'
all_times = 5.times.map{ |i| Time.now + 3600 * 3 * i }
all_times.sort.group_by(&:to_date).each do |day, day_times|
  puts "",day,"-"*40
  day_times.each do |time|
    puts time.strftime(" * %I:%M%P")
  end
end

#=> 2012-01-12
#=> ----------------------------------------
#=>  * 08:56pm
#=>  * 11:56pm
#=> 
#=> 2012-01-13
#=> ----------------------------------------
#=>  * 02:56am
#=>  * 05:56am
#=>  * 08:56am
```